# Scroll Context times out [Elasticsearch 5.6.7]

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am building a worker function to be used to scroll through the data in an Elasticsearch cluster. I am using the `_search` and `scroll` API and `concurrent.futures` in python with the `slice` query for parallelism. I have managed to pull data successfully for a whole month but something seems to be timing out my scroll context prematurely for the last 2 days and can't figure out what. The indexes are grouped in `gameVersion.eventNameAsIndex` but in the search query I just use `gameVersion.*` to bring all indexes for that version. We have about 4 versions and for all except one we have this issue for the last 2 days.

This is the scroller function:

```
def slicedScroller(Index,
                   threadNr,
                   maxThreads,
                   lastRowDateOffset,
                   endDate,
                   maxProcessTimeSeconds,
                   maxSizeMB,
                   esClient,
                   sid=''):
    
    startScroll = time.perf_counter()
    body = {
        "slice": {
            "id": threadNr, 
            "max": maxThreads,
            "field": "baseCtx.date"
        },
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "baseCtx.date"
                    }
                },{
                    "range": {
                        "baseCtx.date": {
                            "gt": lastRowDateOffset,
                            "lt": endDate
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }

    data = []
    dataBytes = b''
    lastThreadDate = ''
    threadTotalHits = 0
    
    while 1:
        if sid == '':
            page = esClient.search(
                index = Index,
                sort = "baseCtx.date:asc",
                scroll = scroll_time,
                size = scroll_size,
                body = body
            )
        elif sid == "nPage":
            break
        elif sid[:5] == "lPage":
            page = esClient.scroll(body={"scroll": scroll_time, "scroll_id": sid[5:]})
        else:
            page = esClient.scroll(body={"scroll": scroll_time, "scroll_id": sid})
        data += page['hits']['hits']
        sid = page["_scroll_id"]
        threadTotalHits = page['hits']['total']
        
        if len(page['hits']['hits']) == 0 and sid[:5] == "lPage":
            sid = "nPage"
            break
        if len(page['hits']['hits']) < scroll_size: # If the length of the page is below scroll_size then it is the last page in the scroll
            sid = "lPage" + sid
            break
        if time.perf_counter() - startScroll > maxProcessTimeSeconds: break # If the amount of time it took to scroll over the slice is bigger than maxProcessingTimeSeconds
        if len(data) > rowsPerMB * maxSizeMB / maxThreads: break # about 12000 rows per compressed MB. If the number of rows is over the amount required to reach maxSizeMB when combining all slices
        # Else continue scrolling
    
    if len(data) != 0:
        dataBytes = gzip.compress(bytes(json.dumps(data)[1:-1], encoding='utf-8'))
        lastThreadDate = max([x['_source']['baseCtx']['date'] for x in data])
    
    response = {
        "sid": sid,
        "threadNr": threadNr,
        "dataBytes": dataBytes,
        "lastThreadDate": lastThreadDate,
        "threadTotalHits": threadTotalHits,
        "threadPulledSize": len(data)
    }
    
    return response
```

The `slicedScroller()` function is called below and results compiled in one file that is then uploaded to a blob storage:

```
def batch(gameVersion, env='prod', startDate='auto', endDate='auto', writeDate=True):
    
    # #### Global Variables
    env = env.lower()
    lowerFormat = gameVersion.lower().replace(" ","_")
    azFormat = re.sub(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '-', gameVersion).lower()
    storageContainerName = azFormat
    curFileName = f"{lowerFormat}_cursor.py"
    curTempFilePath = os.path.join(tempFilePath,curFileName)
    curBlobFilePath = f"cursors/{curFileName}"
    sids = []
    compressedTools = [gzip.compress(bytes('[', encoding='utf-8')), gzip.compress(bytes(',', encoding='utf-8')), gzip.compress(bytes(']', encoding='utf-8'))]

    # Parameter and state settings
    if os.getenv(f"{lowerFormat}_maxSizeMB") is not None: maxSizeMB = int(os.getenv(f"{lowerFormat}_maxSizeMB"))
    if os.getenv(f"{lowerFormat}_maxThreads") is not None: maxThreads = int(os.getenv(f"{lowerFormat}_maxThreads"))
    if os.getenv(f"{lowerFormat}_maxProcessTimeSeconds") is not None: maxProcessTimeSeconds = int(os.getenv(f"{lowerFormat}_maxProcessTimeSeconds"))
    esClient = es(maxThreads)
    
    Index = lowerFormat + ".*"
    if env == 'dev': Index = 'dev.' + Index
    
    try:
        cur = getAndLoadCursor(curBlobFilePath, curTempFilePath)
    except Exception as e:
        dtStr = f"{datetime.datetime.utcnow():%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:00}"
        #writeCursor(curBlobFilePath, f"# Please use format YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS\nlastPolled = '{dtStr}'")
        logging.info(f"No cursor file. Generated {curFileName} file with date {dtStr}")
        print(e)
        return 
    
    # # Scrolling and Batching Engine
    if startDate == 'auto':
        lastRowDateOffset = cur.lastPolled
    else:
        lastRowDateOffset = startDate

    while 1:
        # Offset the current time by -5 minutes to account for the 2-3 min delay in Elasticsearch
        initTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        if endDate == 'auto': endDate = f"{initTime-datetime.timedelta(minutes=minutesOffset):%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}"
        
        dataBytes = []
        dataSize = 0

        start = time.perf_counter()
        
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            ids = list(range(maxThreads))
            if len(sids) == 0: sids = ['' for x in range(maxThreads)]
            #print(f"Posted SIDs: {sids}")
            results = [
                executor.submit(
                    slicedScroller,
                    Index,
                    _id,
                    maxThreads,
                    lastRowDateOffset,
                    endDate,
                    maxProcessTimeSeconds,
                    maxSizeMB,
                    esClient,
                    sid
                ) for _id, sid in zip(ids, sids)
            ]

            for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                if f.result()["sid"][:5] != "nPage":
                    lastRowDateOffset = max(lastRowDateOffset, f.result()["lastThreadDate"])
                    dataSize += f.result()["threadPulledSize"]

                    if len(f.result()["dataBytes"]) > 0: dataBytes.append(f.result()["dataBytes"])

                    sids[f.result()["threadNr"]] = f.result()["sid"]
                    if f.result()["sid"][:5] in ("nPage", "lPage"):
                        sidTest = f.result()["sid"][:5]
                    else:
                        sidTest = 'newSid'
                    print(f"Thread {f.result()['threadNr']} -- Results pulled {f.result()['threadPulledSize']} -- Cumulative Results: {dataSize} -- Process Time: {round(time.perf_counter()-start, 2)} sec -- SID: {sidTest}") #sidTest

        if dataSize == 0: break
        lastRowDateOffsetDT = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastRowDateOffset, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
        outFile = f"elasticsearch/live/{lastRowDateOffsetDT:%Y/%m/%d/%H}/{lowerFormat}_live_{lastRowDateOffsetDT:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}_{datetime.datetime.utcnow():%Y%m%d%H%M%S}.json.gz"
        
        print(f"Starting compression of {dataSize} rows -- {round(time.perf_counter()-start, 2)} sec")
        dataBytes = compressedTools[0] + compressedTools[1].join(dataBytes) + compressedTools[2]
        
        print(f"Comencing to upload data to blob -- {round(time.perf_counter()-start, 2)} sec")
        #uploadJsonGzipBlobBytes(outFile, dataBytes, storageContainerName, len(dataBytes))
        
        logging.info(f"File compiled: {outFile} -- {dataSize} rows -- Process Time: {round(time.perf_counter()-start, 2)} sec")
        print(f"File compiled: {outFile} -- {dataSize} rows -- Process Time: {round(time.perf_counter()-start, 2)} sec\n")
        
        if len(set(sids)) == 1 and list(set(sids))[0] == "nPage": break
    
    if writeDate: 1==1#writeCursor(curBlobFilePath, f"# Please use format YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS\nlastPolled = '{lastRowDateOffset}'")
    logging.info(f"Closing Connection to {esUrl}")
    print(f"Closing Connection to {esUrl}")
    esClient.clear_scroll(scroll_id="_all")
    esClient.close()
    return
```

The `scroll_time="25m"` and `scroll_size=10000`.

Finally when I call `batch("Game Version with Problems")`, sometimes it manages to scroll through and compile at least a file but in most cases, after one scroll I get an error.

```
NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No search context found for id [52908399]')
```

So I did a bit of digging and printed out the scroll_id's used while running and manually POST-ed them on Kibana's dev. It worked and returned the documents requested but even though I stated `scroll_time="25m"`, the same POST request returned the below after 1 minute so I'm guessing that is a timeout:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "search_context_missing_exception",
        "reason": "No search context found for id [51779718]"
      },
      {
        "type": "search_context_missing_exception",
        "reason": "No search context found for id [51779738]"
      },...],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": -1,
        "index": null,
        "reason": {
          "type": "search_context_missing_exception",
          "reason": "No search context found for id [51779718]"
        }
      },
      {
        "shard": -1,
        "index": null,
        "reason": {
          "type": "search_context_missing_exception",
          "reason": "No search context found for id [51779738]"
        }
      },...],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "search_context_missing_exception",
      "reason": "No search context found for id [51773825]"
    }
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

I've checked cluster health and all shards and nodes are green. I've changed the number of threads to 2, 10, then 30, size to 10000 and 5000, scroll time to "1m", "5m", "10m" and "30m". Can't understand how to fix this, why is it happening only on some indexes and why did it start last within the last 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the sliced scroll was causing a high number of open contexts and timed out regardless of the amount I set to keep the scroll id alive. Changed the structure so instead of a sliced scroll I am multithreading on every index. That also means I had to store the last index date per index rather than an index pattern. Even though now I am opening at times 125 threads it doesn't open many contexts and continues scrolling without fail.